# Windows: is there a built in loading animation I can reference as a Visual C++ resource?

Tags: c++, windows, animation, mfc, loading

I am building an Visual C++ MFC project in Visual Studio 2015 that is intended to support Windows 7 and Windows 10. I have learned about DLL files that contain various icons, and also how to reference various cursors, but what I am wondering is if there is a stock "windows loading" animation resource embedded in Windows as a resource that I can reference, either as a file resource or using a win32 API call. This is a difficult thing to find the answer to online because, for example, a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+loading+animation+c%2B%2B&oq=windows+loading+animation+c%2B%2B) yields a bunch of results about icons, loading images, and the loading cursor, none of which are useful for this problem.

To illustrate, here are the specific loading animations for Windows 7:

[image: Windows 7 Loading Animation]

(*this is not a cursor, this is an image anchored to the background*)

and for Windows 10:

[image: Windows 10 Loading Animation]

What I am hoping is that there is some sort of frame-by-frame alpha layered image clips — I intend to handle the rendering and animation of myself.

Comment: This is commonly called a "busy indicator". AFAIK there isn't something like that available for MFC apps. Best you can do is to create a [progress bar control in marquee mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760816(v=vs.85).aspx) using the [PBS_MARQUEE style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/bb760820(v=vs.85).aspx#PBS_MARQUEE).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @zett42. This is one of those things where it is near impossible to find the answer online to the question "Can windows do X?" without asking it on a forum to SMEs. I actually have a progress bar in the view as well, so I will use the MARQUEE for that. It is interesting though with how often Windows draws this graphic that there is not a resource it uses...

Comment: It is [available for UWP apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/progress-controls) (windows store). Most likely there a no resources because this control is drawn dynamically. I think it wouldn't be that difficult to implement it as an MFC owner-drawn control, by deriving from `CStatic`, override `DrawItem()` method, use GDI+ for drawing antialiased dots and update periodically by using a timer. It will consume some time to make it looking good though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows7-style progress circle bitmaps can be found inside of

`Windows\System32\imageres.dll`

with 5000 - 5013 resource ids.

The Windows10-style progress circle is openly available as [ProgressRing XAML control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ProgressRing).

```
<ProgressRing IsActive="True" Height="100" Width="100"/>
```

Comment: Question is tagged "mfc", so a XAML reference isn't helpful.

Comment: Cool, can  weI use this C# control in MFC?

Comment: @TomTom It is not a C# control, it's a uwp control. It can not be used from MFC application though, just like most of the other Win10 uwp stuff.

Comment: The majority of the UWP services **can** be used from an MFC application. GUI classes and implementations that need an app identity are the few exceptions.

Comment: Awesome. In imageres.dll, under PNG\5021 - 5024 the Windows 7 loading sprite is found, in several sizes. I knew it had to be somewhere embedded in the OS!

Comment: However, regarding using UWP services in my MFC application, I have a requirement to build the app **without** using CLR support, so that I can run this in pre-installation environments where .NET is not installed, as well as standard windows environments like Windows 7 and 10 (guess I should've said that earlier).

Comment: @MichaelPlautz: UWP is **native** code. The UWP does not have a dependency on the .NET framework.

Comment: @IInspectable ah, I didn't realize UWP is native. The first tutorial I saw on UWP integration with a VC++ MFC project said to enable CLR support. Now I suppose my next question is going to be, how do I integrate a UWP XAML component onto a standard Win32 Component?

Comment: @MichaelPlautz: You cannot use UWP XAML controls in a desktop application.

Comment: @MichaelPlautz I think you are mistaking WPF XAML (which is essentially .NET based) and UWP XAML (which is COM based, allowing components to be written in various languages, with majority of components shipped with Windows being native). ProgressRing control can not be used by desktop applications directly, however it can be used as a reference or maybe you can dig deeper and figure out some implementation details.